# How to pass parameters to "WHERE IN" query when using a prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, prepared-statement

I've been trying to solve this for days but just can't seem to find a solution.

I'm using Laravel and am trying to execute a Mysql query that has several "WHERE" & "WHERE IN" clauses but if a single "WHERE IN" contains more than one value, the query fails due to it adding quotes around the whole parameter.

I'm passing the parameter as a string. If it contains one value it works fine but fails when it contains multiple.

```
$arrival_location = "PALMA"; // WORKS

$arrival_location = "PALMA, BEIJING"; // FAILS
```

I've tried passing the parameter several different ways but to no avail.

PALMA, BEIJING

'PALMA', 'BEIJING'

"'PALMA', 'BEIJING'"

Here is the query...

```
$travel_data = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT sd.FlightNumber, c1.Country as ArrivalCountry, c1.CityName as ArrivalCity, c2.Country as DepartureCountry, c2.CityName as DepartureCity, a.AirlineName, c1.LatDeg, c1.LonDeg, tp.emergency_name, tp.emergency_relation, tp.emergency_address_line_1, tp.emergency_address_line_2,tp.emergency_city, tp.emergency_country, tp.emergency_post_code, tp.emergency_landline_number, tp.emergency_mobile_number
FROM (SELECT max(PnrBfVersion) as pnrversion, TransactionsID, RecordLocator as recordlocator FROM transactions GROUP BY RecordLocator) as max
JOIN transactions t
ON max.pnrversion = t.PnrBfVersion AND max.recordlocator = t.RecordLocator
LEFT JOIN transaction_details td
ON t.TransactionsID = td.TransactionsID
LEFT JOIN segment_details sd
ON td.TransactionDetailsID = sd.TransactionDetailsID
LEFT JOIN cities c1
ON sd.ArrivalCityCode = c1.CityCode
LEFT JOIN cities c2
ON sd.DepartureCityCode = c2.CityCode
LEFT JOIN airlines a
ON sd.CarrierCode = a.AirlineCode
JOIN traveller_profiles tp
ON td.TravellerID = tp.id
WHERE TravellerID IN (SELECT id FROM traveller_profiles WHERE assigned_manager = ?)
AND TravelType = "10" AND transactionStatus = "T" # Air only and Ticketed data only
AND ArrivalInfo < ?
AND (tp.passenger_first_name LIKE ? OR tp.passenger_last_name LIKE ? OR c1.CityName IN (?) OR c1.Country IN (?) OR c2.CityName IN (?) OR c2.Country IN (?) OR FlightNumber IN (?) OR AirlineName IN (?))'),
array($user_id,
$to_date,
$search_query."%",
$search_query."%",
$arrival_location,
$arrival_country,
$departure_location,
$departure_country,
$flight_number,
$supplier));
```

When checking the MySQL log, I can see that it's adding quotes around the whole parameter.

```
AND (tp.passenger_first_name LIKE 'placeholder%' OR tp.passenger_last_name LIKE 'placeholder%' OR c1.CityName IN ('PALMA, BEIJING CAPITAL') OR c1.Country IN ('') OR c2.CityName IN ('') OR c2.Country IN ('') OR FlightNumber IN ('') OR AirlineName IN (''))
```

When adding in my own quotes, it adds slashes to the query...

```
AND (tp.passenger_first_name LIKE 'placeholder%' OR tp.passenger_last_name LIKE 'placeholder%' OR c1.CityName IN ('\'PALMA\', \'MALTA\'') OR c1.Country IN ('') OR c2.CityName IN ('') OR c2.Country IN ('') OR FlightNumber IN ('') OR AirlineName IN (''))
```

Comment: Have you tried to use an array of values?

Comment: From what I've read, you can't pass an array in a prepared statement. I may be wrong but I haven't seen this been done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass in a single parameter and have it mean a list in the SQL statement.  For this query, you can replace:

```
c1.CityName IN (?)
```

with:

```
find_in_set(c1.CityName, ?) > 0
```

In some cases, this is not a good idea, because it would prevent the use of an index.  In your query, it is unlikely that an index would be used for this `where` clause.

Comment: Thank you for you help Gordon but your solution has only half worked for me.


FIND_IN_SET(c1.CityName, "PALMA, MALTA") > 0
Brings back PALMA.


FIND_IN_SET(c1.CityName, "MALTA, PALMA") > 0
Brings back MALTA.


I can't seem to return both rows.

Comment: Sorry Gordon, made a noob mistake. Should have passed the values with a space in between them. "PALMA,MALTA" is how it should be passed. Not "PALMA, MALTA". Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is wrong. What is DB::select(DB::raw ??

I never seen DB::select used in laravel. I would normally do:

```
DB::table('table')
            ->join('another_table', 'table.id', '=', 'another_table.another_id')
            ->join('yet_another_table', 'table.id', '=', 'yet_another_table.yet_another_id')
            ->select('table.col', 'another_table.col', 'yet_another_table.col')
            ->get();
```

you can pass variables (unquoted) to your join statement.

Some documentation here:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries

Comment: DB::select(DB::raw is used for raw SQL queries when you don't want to use Eloquent. Unquoted variables only appear to work when you have a single where clause. Doesn't work with multiple.